# Is fs the only builtin module that can access the filesystem?

Tags: node.js

I know there are other things like `require` that can access the real filesystem, but this [appears to use `fs` to do so](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/4ddd23f0ec5202b131b7070d543b20cd031f052a/lib/module.js#L594).

Am I right in thinking that there are no other builtins that have *direct* access to the disk?

That is, if I was able to globally overwrite all `fs` methods with my own mocks that read from (and write to) an in-memory virtual filesystem, then there would be no way to access the real filesystem – is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, that is correct. But other modules could spawn processes to access the file system or they could use some native addons that use the file system. If you want to do it as a security measure then it will not be sufficient. If you wanted to make sure that no module can access the real file system then you would have to hijack the system calls on the OS level and make sure that no external process could be run as well. Not an easy task. Probably the same could be achieved easier using containers that would run with an in memory file system and would have no way to access the external file system on the host system, not on the level of JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. So if I disabled the child_process builtin, along with mocking the fs builtin, would that make it impossible (in theory) to access the disk? Or are there other ways that a Node script could spawn a process?

Comment: @callum If you disable or hijack functions exported by `child_process` then other modules that use it (like forever-monitor - see [this line](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever-monitor/blob/master/lib/forever-monitor/common.js#L10)) should not be able to spawn external processes. But modules can have native addons written in C/C++ in which they are able to do much more than in JavaScript - they can use threads for example and use system calls and external libraries. From the built in modules there is also `cluster` that can spawn external processes, I don't know if it uses `child_process`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can access the file system.
Make a child process execute

```
ls
cd ..
nano filename
```

and fetch the result.